# Inclusão PEC da Caixa economia

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, estou com o seguinte problema.

**O erro :**

> soapenv:ServerThe Operation could not be found. The endpoint reference
>   (EPR) for the Operation not found is:
>   'https://des.barramento.caixa.gov.br:7081/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo'
>   and the SOAPAction was
>   'https://des.barramento.caixa.gov.br/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo?wsdl/IncluirBoleto'org.apache.axis2.AxisFault:
>   The Operation could not be found. The endpoint reference (EPR) for the
>   Operation not found is:
>   'https://des.barramento.caixa.gov.br:7081/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo'
>   and the SOAPAction was
>   'https://des.barramento.caixa.gov.br/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo?wsdl/IncluirBoleto'
>   at
>   com.ibm.broker.axis2.Axis2Invoker.invokeAxis2(Axis2Invoker.java:3123)
>   at
>   com.ibm.broker.axis2.TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.invokeAxis2(TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.java:664)
>   at
>   com.ibm.broker.axis2.TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.invokeAxis2(TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.java:610)

**XML request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ext="https://caixa.gov.br/sibar/manutencao_cobranca_bancaria/boleto/externo"
xmlns:sib="https://caixa.gov.br/sibar">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ext:SERVICO_ENTRADA>
      <sib:HEADER>
        <VERSAO>1.0</VERSAO>
        <AUTENTICACAO>Removido por questões de segurança</AUTENTICACAO>
        <USUARIO_SERVICO>Removido por questões de segurança</USUARIO_SERVICO>
        <OPERACAO>INCLUI_BOLETO</OPERACAO>
        <SISTEMA_ORIGEM>SIGCB</SISTEMA_ORIGEM>
        <UNIDADE>Removido por questões de segurança</UNIDADE>
        <DATA_HORA>20180829110000</DATA_HORA>
      </sib:HEADER>
      <DADOS>
        <INCLUI_BOLETO>
          <CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO>Removido por questões de segurança</CODIGO_BENEFICIARIO>
          <TITULO>
            <NOSSO_NUMERO>0</NOSSO_NUMERO>
            <NUMERO_DOCUMENTO>00000011</NUMERO_DOCUMENTO>
            <DATA_VENCIMENTO>2018-09-09</DATA_VENCIMENTO>
            <VALOR>1000.00</VALOR>
            <TIPO_ESPECIE>99</TIPO_ESPECIE>
            <FLAG_ACEITE>S</FLAG_ACEITE>
            <DATA_EMISSAO>2018-08-29</DATA_EMISSAO>
            <JUROS_MORA>
              <TIPO>TAXA_MENSAL</TIPO>
              <VALOR>2.00</VALOR>
            </JUROS_MORA>
            <VALOR_ABATIMENTO>100.00</VALOR_ABATIMENTO>
            <POS_VENCIMENTO>
              <ACAO>DEVOLVER</ACAO>
              <NUMERO_DIAS>999</NUMERO_DIAS>
            </POS_VENCIMENTO>
            <CODIGO_MOEDA>9</CODIGO_MOEDA>
            <PAGADOR>
              <CPF>22222222222</CPF>
              <NOME>TESTE PAGADOR 001</NOME>
              <ENDERECO>
                <LOGRADOURO>SAUS QUADRA 03</LOGRADOURO>
                <BAIRRO>BRASILIA</BAIRRO>
                <CIDADE>BRASILIA</CIDADE>
                <UF>DF</UF>
                <CEP>70070030</CEP>
              </ENDERECO>
            </PAGADOR>
            <MULTA>
              <DATA>2018-09-09</DATA>
              <VALOR>20.00</VALOR>
            </MULTA>
            <DESCONTOS>
              <!--1 to 3 repetitions:-->
              <DESCONTO>
                <DATA>2018-08-30</DATA>
                <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
                <PERCENTUAL>10.00</PERCENTUAL>
              </DESCONTO>
              <DESCONTO>
                <DATA>2018-09-02</DATA>
                <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
                <PERCENTUAL>5.00</PERCENTUAL>
              </DESCONTO>
              <DESCONTO>
                <DATA>2018-09-05</DATA>
                <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
                <PERCENTUAL>3.00</PERCENTUAL>
              </DESCONTO>
            </DESCONTOS>
            <FICHA_COMPENSACAO>
              <MENSAGENS>
                <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WEBSERVICE 1</MENSAGEM>
                <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WEBSERVICE 2</MENSAGEM>
              </MENSAGENS>
            </FICHA_COMPENSACAO>
            <RECIBO_PAGADOR>
              <MENSAGENS>
                <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WS MSG PAG 1</MENSAGEM>
                <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WS MSG PAG 2</MENSAGEM>
                <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WS MSG PAG 3</MENSAGEM>
                <MENSAGEM>TESTE DE INCLUSAO WS MSG PAG 4</MENSAGEM>
              </MENSAGENS>
            </RECIBO_PAGADOR>
            <PAGAMENTO>
              <QUANTIDADE_PERMITIDA>1</QUANTIDADE_PERMITIDA>
              <TIPO>ACEITA_VALORES_ENTRE_MINIMO_MAXIMO</TIPO>
              <VALOR_MINIMO>500.00</VALOR_MINIMO>
              <VALOR_MAXIMO>1500.00</VALOR_MAXIMO>
            </PAGAMENTO>
          </TITULO>
        </INCLUI_BOLETO>
      </DADOS>
    </ext:SERVICO_ENTRADA>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Chamada c#**

```
string baseUrl = "https://des.barramento.caixa.gov.br/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo";

 var xlmParametros = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\ProvasDeConceito\Poc.PEC.Caixa\xml\IncluirBoletoRequestSoap.xml");
    HttpResponseMessage response = PostXmlRequest(baseUrl, "IncluirBoleto", xlmParametros).Result;


     public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostXmlRequest(string baseUrl, string action, string xmlString)
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var httpContent = new StringContent(xmlString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                    string actionFull = baseUrl + "/" + action;
                    httpContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", actionFull);

                    return await httpClient.PostAsync(baseUrl, httpContent);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Recomendo não colocar dados de autenticação(tags: autenticacao, usuario_servico) neste exemplo publico, mesmo sendo referente a ambiente interno de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Leandro, minha resposta respondeu sua pergunta? Se tiver respondido, por favor, marque-a como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Mas faça isso apenas se a resposta tiver respondido sua dúvida original. Quando atingir 15 pontos de reputação também poderá [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Faça também o [tour], para uma explicação inicial de como o site funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está dizendo que o `SOAPAction` que você usou não está sendo encontrado nesse serviço. Eu dei uma olhada no WSDL do serviço, em:

> https://des.barramento.caixa.gov.br/sibar/ManutencaoCobrancaBancaria/Boleto/Externo?wsdl

E notei que o `soapAction` realmente está errado:

```
<wsdl:operation name="INCLUI_BOLETO">
  <soap:operation soapAction="IncluiBoleto"/>
```

Veja que o `soapAction` correto é apenas "IncluiBoleto", e você está usando "IncluirBoleto" (com um "r" a mais que não existe no nome), e ainda está adicionando o conteúdo da variável `baseUrl` ao nome, que também está errado.

Mude esse trecho de:

```
   string actionFull = baseUrl + "/" + action;
   httpContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", actionFull);
```

para:

```
   httpContent.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
```

E mude o nome da ação que você está passando na chamada da função:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = PostXmlRequest(baseUrl,
                                              "IncluiBoleto",
                                              xlmParametros).Result;
```